# How to get page DOM from the chrome extension automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need the chrome extension to get the page code of the page without user clicking on the extension's label. When only a new page is loaded,I whant the code automatically save the DOM html. I want to parse the DOM code of the page, find all the scripts and analytics and block them. How do I implement that?

I have some code getting the DOM of the page, but it works only when the user clicks the label of the chrome extension.
My code:

```
function modifyDOM() {
    return bodyHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
  }

  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: '('+ modifyDOM + ')();'
  },(results)=>{
    console.log(results[0]);
      });
```

I am new to chrome extensions but I think I need to use something like: `web​Request​.onBefore​Request.addListinger()`

Help me please!

Comment: I guess you can try [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)?

Comment: Can you give me an example? There is a lot of information, and also i need a Listiner how will listen the new page opened? Thank you...

Comment: I'm not sure, I also not familiar with it, just make a guess.